# Why generic collection of objects cannot be assigned generic collection of strings in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, generics

I have following sample code in C# that is not behaving according to what I expect. My expectation is that a derived type is implicitly cast to less derived type, and this turns out be the case with `array scenario code` but not with `generic collections scenario code`.

Since a string type is implicitly cast to object type by C#, so the code below should work for both scenarios but it doesn't.

I am assigning an array or collection of strings to an array or collection of objects in code below.

**Question**: 
Why is the generic collection not behaving like an array in code below?

jsfiddle for this code is at [C# code for this question](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qvfcoG)

**C# code**

```
//arrays scenario
object[] objs = new object[3];
string[] strs = new string[] {"a","b","c"};
objs = strs;//THIS WORKS

//Generic collections scenario
List<object> objects = new List<object>();
List<string> strings =  new List<string>{"a","b","c"};
objects = strings; //BUT this does not work
```

Comment: Suppose it did work, and I then called `objects.Add(new HttpClient())` - what would you expect to happen?

Comment: Arrays have covariance, but ordinary `class` types do not. In particular `List<T>` is not covariant in `T`. You can use an interface type such as `IReadOnlyList<out T>` which is covariant (`out`) in `T`.

Comment: Yes, that would ruin everything since you only want a certain type to be in generics collection as they are supposed to provide type-safety. Right?

Comment: But arrays still have the "crazy" covariance even if they are read/write. In the above code, you can add `objs[0] = new HttpClient();` in the bottom, and it would be allowed _at compile-time_. That is crazy. There is a check _at run-time_ that will throw an exception. ___Edit:___ So you are correct there is a difference between arrays and `List<>` in this respect.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen, so arrays are not really type safe unlike generic List collection.  C# considers the second code as incorrect so generic List is always type-safe. Is that right?

Comment: You can say with a generic type, the type-safety is enforced at compile-time. The arrays have a different kind of type-safety because they are covariant. For every _write_ to an array entry, it is checked if the reference you try to assign to the entry, is compatible with the actual run-time type of the array. So the type-safety of arrays is sometimes only enforced when the program runs; you get this: _[`System.ArrayTypeMismatchException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.arraytypemismatchexception.aspx): Attempted to access an element as a type incompatible with the array._

Comment: [Try it online](https://tio.run/##NYs5CoAwEAD7vGJLLQSPUnyCYC8p1lUkoglkgxaSt0fj0c5BnBFTCOzQKQJakRk6a2aLmzgFwCd2o0ZoUekkvWEUUVml514CFtCAno6fVLJ@AjMsE7kYlHeAxUux7HP5DW@RpNF44UO4AA) (check the "Debug" output).

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen, that makes sense. Thanks.